Azure Storage Account: File Access Denied while being connected to a VNet via P2S VPN
I am trying to access a file in the storage account via Azure Portal, while having public network access it set to: Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses.
If i choose the current Virtual Network (including GatewaySubnet), that I am currently connected to via point-to-site Azure VPN Client, I still get the "This machine doesn't seem to have access. This storage account is located in a VNET."
Adding my IP address allows me to see the file. I also I was able to set up a private end point for that storage account, and use Private DNS Resolver with it and had no problem accessing the file.
But i really would like to enable access to the file for anyone on Azure Portal site who is currently connected to a VNet via VPN connection.
Enabled options:
*

Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account.
Routing Preferences: MS Network routing.
GatewaySubnet contains MS.Storage as service.*

Based on the example videos (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LgIwl_El-SI), this should be working, but i am not sure why i am seeing the access denied message, any ideas ?
Thanks in advance.


Hi @VitoldUSA,If you are trying to access the Storage account via VPN, make sure to add the host entry for the Private Endpoint IP and the Storage Endpoint on your local machine. follow the stack link related to same issue.

If you are not using a private endpoint and are only using a selected Virtual Network and IP to access the file share via P2S VPN, it will not connect. You may need to hardcode the storage endpoint IP and FQDN on your local machine, as the Azure Storage public IP can change frequently, follow the MS DOC about same

Thank for a reply, I am trying to use the Virtual Network that i am connected to via P2S VPN. Have a look at the you tube walk through, the guy was able to connect a virtual network and access to the storage account via VM and on Azure Portal Site.

In YouTube Vedio ,He is attempting to access using a VM rather than a P2S VPN. The VM is connected to a Vnet, so it is part of the VNet, but local VM; you must connect via VPN with a host entry(Private endpoint)

If you are also using azure VM  and VMs in the same VNET as storage account, you can also access file share without an issue, but you are using vpn; it may not require vpn if VMs are in the same VNET.

I hope this helps to resolve your issue.


Azure Storage Account: File Access Denied while being connected to a VNet via P2S VPN

The reason you are not able to access Azure File Share via P2S VPN is due to a DNS issue.
If you are not using a private endpoint and are only using a selected Virtual Network and IP to access the file share via P2S VPN, it will not connect. You may need to hardcode the storage endpoint IP and FQDN on your local machine, as the Azure Storage public IP can change frequently.

To resolve the issue, you can use a private endpoint and add a host entry on your local machine with the Private Endpoint IP and the Storage Endpoint.

10.0.0.5    venkatstoragetestdemo.file.core.windows.net

When I tried to access the file share without a host entry, I also faced the same issue.

The issue was resolved after adding the host entry on the local machine.

Azure file share is accessible from P2S VPN

Reference:   Tunneling traffic over a virtual private network or ExpressRoute
Stack Link which is answered by me for same issue

Thank you for such a detailed answer, i will try it today and let you know if it works. Yes, i am not trying to connect VMs to the storage. I am just trying to disable public access and give access to all users that are connecting to Vnet via VPN and have access to azure portal. Thank you again.

The solution worked for me thank you.  Answer accepted.
